# Symfony render controller to get data in twig file

Tags: controller, twig, symfony, render

I'm a bit new to symfony (3.2.1), and I would like to have a controller for each twig file controlling my views to keep my controllers thin as indicated in Symfony Best Pratcices.

In my page, I call

```
{% include "my_bundle/user.html.twig" %}
```

to have a sidebar with all user info, login, etc..

For user.html.twig I would like to have a separate controller, so I created UserController.php.

Seems like the right way to do it, no ?

For now I'm doing a real basic request but can not seem to make it work, though I thought I did everything right.

So src/AppBundle/Controller/UserController.php looks like :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function UserIdAction(Request $request)
    {   
        $userID = '2';

        return $this->render('my_bundle:user.html.twig', array('userID' => $userID));
    }
}
```

and app/Resources/views/my_bundle/user.html.twig looks like :

```
<div id="userSideBar">
    <div class="container">
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Controller:UserId')) }}
        <p>{{ userID }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing that I get error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   _controller value "AppBundle:Controller:UserController" maps to a "AppBundle\Controller\ControllerController" class, but this class was
>   not found. Create this class or check the spelling of the class and
>   its namespace.").

I also tried app/Resources/views/my_bundle/user.html.twig like :

```
<div id="userSideBar">
    <div class="container">
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Controller:UserId', { 'userID': userID })) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But then I get error :

> Variable "userID" does not exist.

Any idea on where I could be wrong please ?

**EDIT :**

I may have missed an important part here :

> To include the controller, you'll need to refer to it using the
>   standard string syntax for controllers (i.e. bundle:controller:action)

So I changed app/Resources/views/my_bundle/user.html.twig to :

```
<div id="userSideBar">
    <div class="container">
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:User:UserId')) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I get :

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes)

and server stops running, really confusing.

Comment: Making this too hard.  Review how to specify a controller method: render(controller('AppBundle:User:UserController',  The fact that you have an action method named UserControllerAction does not really help to keep things clear.

Comment: Yes, the action and the controller having the same name was a bit confusing, so I renamed the action, please see edited question. But I still have the exahausted memory error.

Comment: Think about it.  user.html.twig is calling your user controller which renders user.html.twig again.  Infinite loop.  make a user.siderbar.html.twig file.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking into and missed, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble likes this. When i try to render controller in twig, PHP STORM was show wrong path. As my template was not in root folder Controller it  light me `"AdminBundle:Client\Companies:clientsWidget"` but I was need change slash   `"AdminBundle:Client/Companies:clientsWidget"`